# Anonymous file transfer

Tags: http, proxy, ftp, file-transfer

Does anyone know a way to transfer some files anonymously between 2 computers? 
I intend to hide the IP address of the sender pc.
There is a simple way to do this? For example using tor...

Answer (score 0):

Use a trusted shared storage space. Machine A uploads content to shared storage, machine B fetches content from shared storage. Machine A does not need to know the identity of machine B; machine B does need to know the identity of machine A.